# How to construct a bijection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How to construct a bijection between $[1,6)$ and $(-3,3)$?

I've tried to come up with a proper bijection, but haven't had any luck. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Hint: First, biject $[1,6)$ with $(0,1]$.  Second (the hard part), biject $(0,1]$ with $(0,1)$.  Last, biject $(0,1)$ with $(-3,3)$.

Comment: @vadim123 I haven't thought about it that way. Thanks for the tip, it sure made it easier.

Comment: The very short answer is that your function cannot be continuous.